# best version for Quick Links: ASUS Eee PC 1001PXD-EU17

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, ubuntu-netbook, asus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which flavor of ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1501/which-flavor-of-ubuntu)

I am a total Linux novice and am wondering which version (distro) of Ubuntu should I install on a ASUS Eee PC 1001PXD-EU17. It's a netbook and I hear that Windows 7 Starter is a dog. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Processor: Intel Atom N455 (1.66GHz)
- Memory: 1GB DDR3 Memory
- Graphics: Intel UMA
- HDD: 250GB (5400RPM)
- WLAN: 802.11b/g/n
- Webcam: 0.3MP
- Bluetooth: No Bluetooth
- Battery: 23W/h (Up to 4* Hrs)

Answer (score 4):

You should download and install  Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit. Unfortunately, this netbook does not support 64-bit Ubuntu, so trying to boot from the disk would result in an error. You can get Ubuntu at [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/). Click "Get Ubuntu" towards the bottom of the page. Click Download and Install. Click "Start Download" (the big orange button). Burn the disk image (.ISO) to a USB flash drive and boot from it on the netbook. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, WarriorIng64, I'm on a mobile device and auto-correct sometimes makes stupid corrections that I miss when proofreading.

Comment: I think it supports 64-bit on its own! Check this http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201202-10627/

Answer (score 1):

My brother got a new Eee PC 1015PX-MU17 at the start of the school year, which I imagine would be comparable to your model. It came with Windows 7 Starter installed, which *was* painfully slow to use. We set his system up to dual-boot with 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, and he was very happy with the large speed boost it came with.

Whichever version of Ubuntu you decide to use, you should use the 32-bit version (64-bit cannot run on your processor). The default interface in 10.04 LTS should work just fine on your netbook, although if you go with 11.10 you should probably stick with Unity 2D to conserve on system resources. If you really want, you may also give Xubuntu or Lubuntu a look, as they try to be very low on system resource usage.

You may refer to my linked question below if you need help with partitioning when you perform your install:

[Recommended dual-boot partitioning for Eee PC 1015PX-MU17](https://askubuntu.com/q/56398/18612)